# Передача лямбды шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, lambda

Как передать в шаблон с параметром-функцией лямбду? Почему так не работает?

Минимальный пример такой:

```
template <typename T>
void invoke(std::function<void(T)> f, T val)
{
    f(val);
}

int main()
{
    auto printer = [](int x){ std::cout << x; };
    ::invoke(printer, 42);
}
```

Я конечно могу явно указать `::invoke<int>` или в параметре функции int указать, но тогда это нужно делать при каждом вызове и нет смысла в шаблоне... Как сделать, чтобы в общем случае вызов `::invoke(...)` работал?

P.S.: просто поменять `std::function` на шаблонный параметр нельзя (т.к. нужно переделывать кучу кода тогда)

Comment: Не работает потому, что из передаваемого типа `anonymous_class` нет возможности вывести параметр шаблона `T`. Непонятно, зачем вам нужна эта функция, если есть `std::invoke`.

Answer (score 5):

Если шаблонный параметр фигурирует в типе какого-то параметра функции и при этом находится там в т.наз. *дедуцируемом контексте* (deduced context), то соответствующий шаблонный аргумент будет дедуцироваться компилятором из типа соответствующего аргумента функции. При этом требуется чтобы:

1. все дедукции таких шаблонных аргументов (в каждом параметре функции) были успешными, и
2. все дедукции одного и того же шаблонного аргумента давали один и тот же результат

То есть вот такой пример

```
template <typename T> struct S { S(T) {} };

template <typename T> void foo(T t, S<T> s) {}

int main() 
{
  foo(5, 5);
}
```

компилироваться не будет, т.к. дедукция шаблонного аргумента `T` из типа второго аргумента функции завершается безуспешно. Тот факт, что шаблонный аргумент `T` успешно дедуцируется из типа первого аргумента функции, никак ситуацию не спасает.  В данном примере `T` находится в дедуцируемом контексте и в первом, и во втором параметре. Это значит, что дедукция должна выполняться через оба параметра и должна завершаться успешно в обоих (и должна выводить одно и то же значение `T`). В противном случае код некорректен.

Подавить это деструктивное поведение второго параметра функции можно, если в объявлении этого параметра умышленно поместить `T` в *недедуцируемый контекст* (non-deduced context). Например, если тип второго параметра описать как вложенный тип постороннего шаблона-оболочки

```
template <typename T> struct S { S(T) {} };

template <typename T> struct W
{
  using S = ::S<T>;
};

template <typename T> void bar(T t, typename W<T>::S s) {}

int main() 
{
  bar(5, 5);
}
```

В этом варианте второй аргумент функции исключается из процесса дедукции `T` и дедукция `T` выполняется только на основе первого аргумента (и проходит успешно).

Ваш пример страдает от этой же самой проблемы. То есть в вашем примере работоспособный "костыль" может выглядеть так

```
template <typename T> struct W
{
  using F = std::function<void(T)>;
};

template <typename T> void invoke(typename W<T>::F f, T val)
{
  f(val);
}

int main()
{
  auto printer = [](int x){ std::cout << x; };
  ::invoke(printer, 42);
}
```

Вполне может быть, что я упускаю уже готовое стандартное средство для решения этой же проблемы этим же способом.

Comment: Чтобы не делать отдельный класс-оболочку на каждый такой случай, можно использовать `std::enable_if_t<1, std::function<void(T)>>`. Еще вариант: `std::common_type_t<std::function<void(T)>>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Я вот как раз ищу какой-то `std::identity_wrapper` или что-то в этом роде. Или лучше `std::non_deduced`. Варианты с `std::enable_if` и т.п., разумеется, работают, но на первый взгляд сбивают с толку.

Comment: То есть играет роль порядок аргументов? Если объявить `foo(T t, S<T> s)` будет выводить?

Comment: @Cerbo: Нет, не играет. Я же написал: требуется, чтобы **все** дедукции шаблонных аргументов (в каждом параметре функции) были успешными. **Все**. Порядок не важен. В моём примере невозможно дедуцировать `T` из аргумента `5` для параметра типа `S<T>`. Это всегда будет "падать", где бы в списке параметров это `S<T>` ни располагалось.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать вариадик-шаблон, тогда вам не придется менять уже существующий код:

```
template <typename function_t, typename... args_t>
decltype(auto) invoke_args(function_t _function, args_t&&... _args)
{
    return (_function)(std::forward<args_t>(_args)...);
}

void f_printer(int x)
{
    std::cout << "f_" << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto printer = []() { std::cout << "empty" << std::endl; };
    auto printer1 = [](int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
    auto printer2 = [](int x, int y) { std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl; };

    invoke_args(f_printer, 42); // f_42
    invoke_args(printer); // empty
    invoke_args(printer1, 42); // 42
    invoke_args(printer2, 42, 84); // 42 84

    system("pause");
}
```

Такой шаблон будет работать с переменным числом аргументов и будет возвращать тип в соответствии с типом возврата функции

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к [ответу @AnT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/908785/312941).

В C++20 в `<type_traits>` появилась метафункция [std::type_identity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity), с помощью которой можно делать то же самое, что @AnT описывает в ответе:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> void invoke(std::type_identity_t<std::function<void(T)>> f, T val)
{
  f(val);
}

int main()
{
  auto printer = [](int x){ std::cout << x; };
  ::invoke(printer, 42);
}
```

[Оригинальное предложение](https://wg21.link/p0887r0); [ревизия оригинального предложения](https://wg21.link/p0887r1), одобренная в июне 2018.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже указано в комментарии под вопросом, проблема в невозможности вывести тип `T` из лямбды при инстанцировании шаблона.

Я вижу как минимум два возможных решения:

- Заменить `auto` на конкретный тип функтора `std::function<void(int)>`.
- Добавить шаблонную версию с двумя параметрами:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename F>
  void invoke(F f, T val)
  {
      f(val);
  }
  ```

  Тогда лямбда будет распознаваться как тип `F` в новой реализации.